# Webkit component for Android

Tags: android, webkit

Is there a Webkit component/class for Android except the standard WebView? I have had enough of it, with its super-duper non-disabling options like image dithering on touch etc.

I'm looking for a component that is easy enough to embed in a hello-world application, since I'm newbie in Android development. Actually, the whole application of mine is HTML5 web-app, I just need a way to present it without distortions.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably would not be easier than using a WebView, especially if you are a beginner. But check out the various classes in the [android.webkit package](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/). Follow the link and expand android->webkit on the folders to the left.

Comment: Of course, using the WebView is the easiest option. The problem is it doesn't behave like a normal browser's supposed to do and has no settings. I cannot believe it, but supporting Android web-app seems to be more painful than iOS although I used to think otherwise. OK, maybe some clue how to stick the classes into a component?

Comment: has no settings? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html it has an entire class made to encapsulate its settings...

Comment: Yep, formally there is a lot of them, but no one for such critical task like disabling image dithering on touch, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042085/images-get-pixelated-when-the-screen-is-touched As you can see, there is no solution, just workaround, and the workaround is not good enough, since buttons stop to be pressed.

Comment: I'm not kidding about criticality. This "feature" strikes through the HTML5 games on Android with a bold line. Help me to get rid of it and you are my hero of the Android development. I wasted several days looking for a solution (to no avail).